# ng-click loose the function context

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-click

I am using angularjs.
I have a directive that gets a function as parameter:

```
module.directive('someDirective', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: <button ng-click="doClick()">blabla</button>,
        scope: {
            doClick: '='
        }
    };
}]);
```

I am using this directive like that:

```
<some-directive do-click="funcOnScope"></some-directive>
```

And everything works perfectly.
Now I have the following on my scope:

```
$scope.a = {
    data: { name: 'myname' },
    action: function() {
        alert(this.data.name);
    }
}
```

When calling to:

```
<some-directive do-click="a.action"></some-directive>
```

I am expecting to get an alert with 'myname' when clicking on the button. But I get an exception that data is undefined. This is happening because "this" is referencing to window (angular calls to the ng-click function without a context).
How can I call a.action() without loosing the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the scope definition to

```
scope: {
  doClick: '&'
}
```

and call it like that

```
<some-directive do-click="a.action()"></some-directive>
```

[here is jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nawrockim/kP5HT/8/)

Comment: if you define the scope with '=' your function will be executed couple of times ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is *the* correct answer, but it will suffice.  Perform a `bind` on a.action in the `do-click` attribute:

```
<some-directive do-click="a.action.bind(a)"></some-directive>
```

This will force the function to keep the `a` context.

Comment: This is a nice workaround but I was looking for the angular way